# Options to drag and drop with synergy KVM switch?

Tags: linux, windows, android, synergy, kvm-switch

I am effectively using Synergy between Windows/Linux/Android
However, I am trying to find a way to drag and drop.

I know I can "just network a drive, and modify a [send to], but honestly, when it comes to rapid work - easier saves my patience.

The Server is Windows 8.1, (I can change this if I must, but I rather not)

The Clients in question are Windows XP+, Linux and the Android I am not worried about.

please advise

Comment: You want to drag & drop items between two separate physical machines between which you switch with a KVM switch?

Comment: Using with, or in conjunction with; Synergy.